# Running junit plugin test suite fails due to concurrent modification exception In arrayList.java

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

When I run my junit test suite I get failures but when I run them individually they all pass.

I run on Mac OSX El Capitan but other developers use Windows 7. When they run the same tests as we all contribute to the same repository, their tests pass without any problems. Does anyone know if there is a difference between the two operating systems that would cause a problem with my tests being run differently.

I am running eclipse Mars.1 with Oracle Java 7 and they are using Kepler and Mars with IBM java 7 and 8. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, one gets that exception when they're are trying to modify the list they're iterating through. Maybe post your test class so that we can see

Comment: Now that's the strange part